# Unbound textbox not requerying or refreshing

Tags: vba, ms-access, textbox

I have 3 unbound textboxes

- `textbox1` enter a number
- `textbox3` enter a number
- `textbox5` total of the two textbox

I put this code in `Form_Current()`

```
Text5 = Val(Text1) + Val(Text3)
```

The problem is that after entering the two numbers, `text5` don't show the total.

I tried used `textbox5.requery` in `Form_Current()` but it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the `current` event for this

Create the following sub:

```
Private Sub Compute_Text5()
    Text5.value = Val(Text1.value) + Val(Text3.value)
End Sub
```

And add an `AfterUpdate()` event to `Text1` and `Text3` in order to trigger your computation whenever the values on any of the 2 textBoxes are changed:

```
Private Sub Text1_AfterUpdate()
    Compute_Text5
End Sub  

Private Sub Text3_AfterUpdate()
    Compute_Text5
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`Form_Current()` and `.Requery` are only useful for bound controls.

You don't really need VBA for this, simply use this as control source of Text5:

```
= Val([Text1]) + Val([Text3])
```